# How to fix double-encoded and mangled strings in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unicode

My process is dealing with data that has been mangled. I can tell that it has been double-encoded in UTF-8 but this is only half the story. Double-*decoding* only works for code points that are single-byte (latin) and that pass through UTF-8 unscathed. The double-byte (or larger) code points cannot be double-decoded using `.decode('utf-8').encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('utf-8')`

I have an example that will serve as a help in figuring this out. One of the strings I have coming through is this:

```
'\xc3\x82\xc2\xa9\xc3\x82\xc2\xae\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9e\xc2\xa2'
```

This is supposed to resolve to:

```
u'\xa9\xae\u2122'
```

The first two code points for (c) and (r) symbols do not need surrogate pairs and so are very obviously present in the raw bytes. However, the final character, the (tm) symbol, is a 16-bit code point and gets mangled by whatever process did this.

If I chop off the string before that point then I can double-decode successfully:

```
'\xc3\x82\xc2\xa9\xc3\x82\xc2\xae'.decode('utf-8').encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('utf-8')
```

However, this doesn't work for the entire string because the first decoding results in this:

```
u'\xc2\xa9\xc2\xae\xe2\u201e\xa2'
```

Can anyone point me in the correct direction for solving this? I'll continue poking at this in the meantime and see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Alright so I essentially just had to make some guesses at the encoding until I came up with the solution. The problem is that the data was cp1252 encoded as well (probably because the data is coming from a Windows system). The solution is to call `.decode('utf-8').encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')` and *voila*:

```
>>> raw = '\xc3\x82\xc2\xa9\xc3\x82\xc2\xae\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\x9e\xc2\xa2'
>>> print raw.decode('utf-8').encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')
©®™
```

I hope someone else gets help by stumbling across this!

Found this which helped too:

https://gist.github.com/litchfield/1282752/653b0c1944741ac90ca9c63c25ee3c2f609b323b