# Python multiple special characters in csv file

Tags: python, utf-8, decode, encode, utf

I have an csv file with some data that contains string like this:

```
string = 'übung ÃœberprÃ¼fung'
```

and I want my programm to read it or convert it into the right format:

```
'übung Überprüfung'
```

My current solution:

```
print(string.encode('cp1252', 'ignore').decode('utf-8','replace'))
```

Output: `�bung Überprüfung`

I have been struggling with this for ours and days.
Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: It looks like a mixed encoding of cp1252 and UTF-8 being displayed as cp1252 (or similar).  Garbage in, garbage out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the whole file is encoded in cp1252 (we are not dealing with an incorrectly encoded file), the best approach would be to specify it's encoding when the file is opened:

```py
with open("data.csv", "r", encoding="cp1252") as csvfile:
    ...
```

Comment: If you are already doing this, or it doesn't help, you are likely dealing with mangled encoding. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50066618/how-to-fix-double-encoded-and-mangled-strings-in-python or https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I already  read the file as:csv_file = pd.read_csv(filepath, delimiter=';')

Comment: Try to add `encoding="cp1252"` to `read_csv()` call then. See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html